# Relationship between Crossing Number & Genus of space!

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The Crossing number of a graph is the minimum value of crossing point amongst all drawings...

on the other hand, Via Euler formula, we know that a graph is embeddable in a space with sufficiently large genus.

but you can consider every hole in (high genus) space as a bridge (handle) that some edges can go through it, also any crossing point may be considered as a bridge which one edge can passed away...

The Question is what's the relationship between these two concepts?

Trivially $Cr>g$ But is there any well known better (in)equality?

Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have observed, for any graph $G$, we always have 
$$cr(G)\geq g(G)\tag{1}$$
where $cr(G)$ is the [crossing number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)) of $G$ and $g(G)$ is the [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Graph_theory) of $G$.

On the other hand, the difference between the crossing number and the genus of a graph can be arbitrarily large, as we can see from this example: The crossing number of $C_3\times C_n$, the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) of the cycle $C_3$ and $C_n$, is given by $cr(C_3\times C_n)=n$ for $n\geq 3$ (see [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009589567890014X)) . On the other hand, it is easy to show that the genus of $C_3\times C_n$ is given by $g(C_3\times C_n)=1$ for $n\geq 3$.

So I would say $(1)$ is the only relationship we have between crossing number and genus.

Comment: Thanks... but i hope that there was a formula with some restrictions...